# C# casting variable double to float

Tags: c#, casting, double

How do you cast a variable containing a double into a float?

I understand we can do this.

```
float deltaXPow = Math.Pow(2f, 3f);
```

But what I need to do is cast the variable.  I've tried doing it this way but it doesn't seem to work.

```
float deltaYPow = Math.Pow((float)deltaY, (float)power2);
```

This doesn't work.

EDIT:

I'm working on an assignment to find the hyp and the angle of point a and point b.  This is for Unity C#

```
float deltaX = firstValueX - secondValueX;
float deltaY = firstValueY - secondValueY;

//<Notes>
//These lines of code will find delta x and y squared.
//Created const double for 2 because this number does not change.
//<Notes>
const float power2 = 2;

float deltaXPow = Math.Pow(deltaX, power2);
Console.WriteLine($"Delta X to the power of 2 is {deltaXPow}.");

float deltaYPow = Math.Pow(deltaY, power2);
Console.WriteLine($"Delta Y to the power of 2 is {deltaYPow}.");

//<Notes>
//The following lines of code will add the two squared numbers together and 
//resolve to square root of that number.
//<Notes>
float hypotenuse = Math.Sqrt((float)deltaXPow + (float)deltaYPow);
Console.WriteLine($"The hypotenuse of the points entered is {hypotenuse}.");

//<Notes>
//
//<Notes>
float atanRad = Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
```

This code errors out with the follow = Cannot explicitly convert 'double' to 'float'

Because this is C# unity all values need to be in float.

Comment: yeah, bc it makes no sense. `Math.Pow()` expects `double` arguments

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? What problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: Yes I understand but because this is for Unity C# it requires float variables that have to be converted.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please provide exactly what your problem is. Not all of us have a ready compiler in their head to guess what your problem might be.

Comment: If you really must do it it's float deltaXPow = (float) Math.Pow(2, 3);  But why not just use doubles?

Comment: I have added the full code.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that did the trick.  (float) casting has to be done before Math.Pow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the vague post.  I have updated the post with more info.

This was resolved by Mark.

```
(float)Math.Pow(variableX, variableY);
```

Did the trick.